# How to remove branch and remove changes made in branch

Tags: git

I started a new branch and made a lot of changes, to controllers, database, models, etc as I was testing a new feature to see if I wanted to keep it or trash it.

I now want to trash that branch without any of the changes being save or merged to my master branch. I want to completely get rid of it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do `git branch -D name_branch`

and `git push origin :name_branch` to remove it from your origin also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First command went through and second command left these errors. `error: unable to delete 'new-carrierwave': remote ref does not exist` and `error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:licatajustin/..`

Comment: @Justin You can always check if this branch appears on your remote with the following command : git branch -r. A list of branches will appear if your branch_name isn't there then your are ok (the branch will not affect your origin)